# Does WPA PSK/Personal break PMK?

Tags: encryption, wifi, wpa-enterprise

I am not sure about the difference between WPA-PSK TKIP and WPA-Enterprise TKIP key generation.

**Do they both generate same keys from PMK, but for different purposes or are they created through a totally different process?**

Answer (score 4):

The PMK is used the same after generation, however they are generated very differently. With WPA-PSK the PMK is generated from the PSK, fundamentally if one knows the PSK one can access the network. With WPA-Enterprise this is a little different as 802.11x does EAP authentication to a RADIUS server and then the RADIUS server gives the PSK in the parameters it sends back after successful authentication and can give a different one for each authentication, therefore every client is using a different PSK, and each session can give a new PSK.